# releasing icons/bitmaps Winforms.

Tags: winforms

I have resources, icons and images, in a separate resource project. It exposes the resources in its auto generated classes as static members with types of Icon and Bitmap.

I assume those I add to imagelists and controls will be looked after by those controls when disposed.

There are others where I will get a Bitmap from the resources class and convert it to an icon.

```
Bitmap image = Resources.StatusPic;
Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(image.GetHicon());
```

Does this create an image that needs releasing and an icon?

Equally, if for some reason I did something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Icon icon = Resources.Busy;
    Image image = Resources.StatusPic;

}
```

Assuming it isn't optimised out, does that create 10 icons and 10 pics that aren't properly released? I had a quick look at the code generated in the resource class and it wasn't clear that it wasn't.

I'm just a bit concerned about GDI resources here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons and Bitmaps implement the `IDisposable` interface. Call their `Dispose()` method if you do not use them anymore.